# The cubic equation $x^3 - 4 x^2 + x + 1 =0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, cubics

- The cubic polynomial
  $P(x) = x^{3} - 4x^{2} + x + 1$ has [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) $\Delta = 169 = 13^{2}$ which tells us that the extension $\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q}$ is normal, where $a$ is any root of the equation $P(x) = 0$.
- Therefore, given one root $a$, one can find the other as polynomial expressions in $a$.
- For instance, in this case it is not hard to check  that the other roots are $a^{2} - 4a + 2$ and $-a^{2} + 3 a + 2$. But what if we didn't know these expressions? Is there a way to get them?

Comment: Sure; use long division to divide $x^3-4x^2 + x + 1$ by $(x-a)$, and solve the resulting quadratic using the quadratic theorem.

Comment: @Slade: I see, you get $ 1/2 (\pm \sqrt{-3 a^2+8 a+12}-a+4)$, that is pretty good, but can we get it as a polynomial in $a$? Your method would work for any cubic equation, normal or not.

Comment: What is the definition you use for $\Delta$? (I get another value than $13^2$)

Comment: @Piquito: Hi, thanks for asking, I added a link in the text to the definition on wikipedia.

Comment: @orangeskid The square root can be computed in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.  We have to use that the discriminant is a square at _some_ point, and it gets used precisely in solving for $\sqrt{-3a^2 + 8a+12} = \pm(2a^2-7a)$.

Comment: We can also use the fact that the square root of the discriminant is $\pm(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$.  Given that the coefficients of the quadratic are $-(b+c)$ and $bc$, this gives some reasonably simple equations to solve.

Comment: @Slade: Yes, now I see it. Thanks, that looks great. The equations are simple, since $(b-c) = \pm\sqrt{\Delta}/((a-b)(a-c)) = \pm\sqrt{\Delta}/P'(a)$. We also know $(b+c) = s_1-a$. It turns out to be very simple indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Slade: So you gave  a quick and easy solution to the general problem of expressing the other roots over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$.   Also, inverting $P'(a)$ uses again the resultant of $P$ and $P'$, that is, the discriminant... Neat!

Comment: Please add an answer containing the solution hinted at in the comments.

Comment: @orangeskid: tell me please if $\Delta$ being a square then the extension with just one root, it is normal. I can't see why. Thank you.

Comment: @Piquito: The formulas for the other roots of an equation $x^3 + p x^2 + q x + r $ are $b,c = \frac{1}{2}( -p -a \pm \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{P'(a)} )$ so if $\sqrt{\Delta}$ is in the base field $K$ then all the roots are in $K(a)$.  ( if $\Delta =0$ consider  $\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{P'(a)}=0$ )

Comment: Oh, thank you orangeskid! In this case, all is clear because $b$ and $c$ are rational functions of $a$ and necessarily the image of $a$ by all element of the Galois group distinct of identity is another root (here this means $b$ or $c$)

Comment: @Piquito: Yes, and these expressions are in fact Galois transformations. However, we could conclude that the extension is normal without apriori knowing the formulas.  This would use some field theory

Comment: @orangeskid: I fear, at first sight, not very responsible, that even use of class field theory (Kronecker-Weber, this is as first appearance your problem underlying if using class field theory).

Comment: Do you mean with " without apriori knowing the formulas" that without knowing $\Delta$ is square?

Comment: @Piquito: Hi, I mean theory of field extensions, not class field theory ( much more sophisticated). But in general, the splitting field of a cubic is a normal extension of $K(\sqrt{\Delta})$ obtained by the addition of any root. Knowing this, I was curious about how the other roots are expressed in terms of a given root.  After we have the formulas, we can reason in reverse. I think both approaches are useful. I plan to ask another general question about it.

Comment: @lhf:  managed at last to write the answer hinted in the comments by slade.  The general formula is still fairly complicated.

Comment: @Slade: finally got the answer as you indicated, thanks!

Comment: FWIW [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4676881/291201) is a quintic having the discriminant a perfect square.

Comment: @dxiv: Wow, yes... There is another version [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMoivresQuintic.html)... interesting stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $P(x) = x^3 - 4 x^2 + x + 1$ is normal, $P(x)$ splits in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$.

This means that the polynomial will factor into linear factors over $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$. One of the factors will be $(x - \alpha)$. The others will be $(x - (\alpha^2 - 4 \alpha + 2))$ and $(x - (-\alpha^2 + 3 \alpha + 2))$

You can calculate these polynomials quickly using factorization modulo an ideal, for example in pari/gp:

```
? f(x) = x^3 - 4*x^2 + x + 1
%1 = (x)->x^3-4*x^2+x+1
? factor(Mod(f(x),f(a)))
%2 = 
[            x + Mod(-a, a^3 - 4*a^2 + a + 1) 1]

[x + Mod(-a^2 + 4*a - 2, a^3 - 4*a^2 + a + 1) 1]

[ x + Mod(a^2 - 3*a - 2, a^3 - 4*a^2 + a + 1) 1]
```

---

If you were just working with pencil and paper you could perform the long division of $P(x)/(x-\alpha)$ modulo $P(\alpha)$.

This gives $x^2 + (\alpha - 4) x + (\alpha^2 - 4\alpha + 1)$ which you can now try to factorize into two linear factors.

Answer (score 2):

(Finally got the solution indicated by @slade: in his comments, thanks!)

Recall that for polynomials $P(x)$, $Q(x)$ we have an expression

$$A(x) P(x) + B(x) Q(x) = R$$
where $R$ is the resultant of $P$, $Q$. In particular, for the discriminant $R = \Delta$ of $P$ we have an expression

$$A(x) P(x) + B(x) P'(x) = \Delta  \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

where for $P(x)$ of degree $n$ we have $A(x)$ of degree $n-2$, and $B(x)$ of degree $n-1$.

For $P(x) = x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c$, we'll get the explicit $A(x)$, $B(x)$ below.

In any case, assume that we have a cubic polynomial

$$P(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$$

From here we get

$$P'(x) = (x-x_2)(x-x_3) + (x-x_1)(x-x_3) + (x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$

and so

$$P'(x_1) = (x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)$$

Now, for the discriminant $\Delta$ we have

$$\pm \sqrt{\Delta} =  (x_2-x_3)(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)$$

and so

$$(x_2-x_3) = \pm \frac{\sqrt{\Delta} }{P'(x_1)}$$

but now  from $(*)$ and $P(x_1) = 0$ we get

$$P'(x_1) = \frac{\Delta}{B(x_1)}$$

so in the end

$$x_2-x_3= \pm \frac{B(x_1)}{\sqrt{\Delta}}$$

Now, for $P(x) = x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c$ we have in the [equality](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%20%28-6%28a%5E2%20-%203%20b%29x%20%2B%20%28-4%20a%5E3%20%2B%2015%20a%20b%20-%2027%20c%29%20%29%28x%5E3%20%2B%20a%20x%5E2%20%2B%20b%20x%20%2B%20c%29%2B%28%202%28a%5E2%20-%203%20b%29%20x%5E2%20%2B%20%28%202%20a%5E3%20-%207%20a%20b%20%2B%209%20c%29%20x%20%2B%20%28a%5E2%20b%20-%204%20b%5E2%20%2B%203%20a%20c%29%20%29%283%20x%5E2%20%2B%202%20a%20x%20%2B%20b%29) $(*)$

$$A(x) = -6(a^2 - 3 b)x + (-4 a^3 + 15 a b - 27 c) \\
B(x) = 2(a^2 - 3 b) x^2 + ( 2 a^3 - 7 a b + 9 c) x + (a^2 b - 4 b^2 + 3 a c) $$

Let's also recall that
$$x_2 + x_3 = -a - x_1$$

We get

$$x_{2,3} = \frac{1}{2}( - a-x_1 \pm \frac{B(x_1)}{\sqrt{\Delta}} )$$

Let's consider our example with the equation $x^3 - 4 x^2 + x + 1$. We have $a=-4$, $b=1$, $c=1$, $\Delta= 13^2$, so we [get](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F2%28%20-%20a%20-%20x%20%2B%20%28%202%28a%5E2%20-%203%20b%29%20x%5E2%20%2B%20%28%202%20a%5E3%20-%207%20a%20b%20%2B%209%20c%29%20x%20%2B%20%28a%5E2%20b%20-%204%20b%5E2%20%2B%203%20a%20c%29%20%29%2Fd%29%2F.%20%7Ba-%3E-4%2C%20b-%3E1%2C%20c-%3E1%2C%20d-%3E%7B13%2C-13%7D%7D)
$$x_{2,3} = x^2 - 4 x + 2  \textrm{ and } -x^2 + 3 x + 2 $$